# icon Inaction bar not visiable

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image: i want icon like this image]
**i want icon like in above image problem is that icon appears on action bar in preview but on device these icon does not visible they are like below image**
[image: screen on device look like this] **here is my menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<item android:id="@+id/action_list"
    android:icon="@drawable/list"
    android:title="list"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_grid"
    android:icon="@drawable/grid"
    android:title="grid"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**here is my Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest><br>
```

any help will be appreciable. please help me thanks.

Comment: Could you show your MainActivity?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get it to work either. My activity couldn't extend ActionBarActivity, and I ended up doing `android:showAsAction="always"` which worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally find answer of this problem this occur because of wrong theme slove this by using `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` theme instead of `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`.